# Ubuntu 16.04 crashes on startup with below logs

Tags: 16.04, kernel, crash

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and I am getting the below errors (check attachments) while startup.

It starting sometimes normally but even in this case it's hanging (crashing) in 5-10 mins and then I need to shut down forcefully

Can anyone suggest what could be the root cause? What could be a potential solution?

[image]

Comment: Do you dual-boot between Windows and Ubuntu? If so, do you have "Fast Startup" enabled? That `Fatal exception in interrupt` says it's a hardware issue, but I've seen a similar thing when Windows has "Fast Startup" enabled, which leaves storage partitions in a weird state that can cause problems on older versions of Linux.

Comment: Hi @Matigo No I am not doing dual-boot between Windows and Ubuntu. It's just an Ubuntu machine. I am using a different laptop charger recently (as I missed the original one at the relative place) can it be related?

Comment: If your machine is not getting the proper amount of power, then there's certainly a chance this could be causing the issue. If you run off battery, does the problem exist?

Comment: Hi @Matigo Thank you, unfortunately, there is no option to remove battery easily in my laptop model (it's all inside)

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you remove the battery, but instead boot using *only* the battery. If the battery can provide a more consistent flow of power, then you can safely assume that the replacement charger you're using is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this for others who might face a similar issue and it may help. I had issue with my memory (RAM). I removed the memory from one slot (I had added extra memory on extra slot) and then the issue resolved. Also, I have added the same memory after a few days of testing, still, it's working properly so I can assume that it could be an issue that RAM was not fitted properly with the slot module.

I had traveled with the laptop it and the project started just after that, so my guess is RAM could be slightly moved from its module.

Hope it helps someone.